# How to strikethrough text in VBA - Programmatically?

Tags: vba, ms-access, format, text-formatting

Is there a way to strike through text in VBA *(Access)* programmatically?

For example; When I click on a button, I'd like to change `Hello World!` to `H̶e̶l̶l̶o̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶l̶d̶!̶`

---

**Edit #1:** Just realised that there isn't a strikethrough possibility (as far as I know) within VBA so this question is answered. For those who wonder if it's possible.. It's most likely not.

Comment: It's possible, you should mention which one. Excel/Word/etc.In Excel, try `ActiveCell.Font.Strikethrough = True`

Comment: @PatricK Ah, I'm sorry. I mean Visual Basic for Applications (Access)

Comment: Haven't worked on Access VBA, start from [Acces MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192120.aspx)

Comment: @PatricK Yeah, I figured haha. Thanks for your answer however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this while google-ing for the same issue:

1. Create 2 Text Boxes named `txtText` and `txtOverlay`.
2. Make these 2 Text Boxes exactly the same size, either by code or manually.
3. Place `txtOverlay` exactly on top of `txtText`, again, either by code or
   manually.
4. Run the following code wherever appropriate:

   ```
   Const conTransparent = 0

   'Should be a Fixed Width Font
   Me![txtText].FontName = "Courier New"
   Me![txtText].FontSize = 12
   Me![txtText] = "Your text"

   Me![txtOverlay].FontName = "Courier New"
   Me![txtOverlay].FontSize = 12
   Me![txtOverlay].BackStyle = conTransparent
   Me![txtOverlay] = String(Len(Me![txtText]), "-")
   ```

Credit goes to the guy who came up with it:
https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/722250-strikethrough-text

Hope it helps!